# How to reference existing entity using Inline Entity Form?

Tags: entities

I'm using Entity Reference to create tasks in lists - both tasks and lists are content type, list contains multivalue Entity Reference to task. Because most tasks belong to only one list, it was only natural to use [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).

Problem is *most* - there are *some* tasks that needs to belong to many lists.

Module's docs says:

> Existing entities can also be referenced.

That would do the trick. My question is very simple: **How do I do that?** Only button I see is "Add new node", and it opens node creation form. What should I do to see "Add existing node"?

Comment: +1 I don't know why this was downvoted, I have the same question ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*To add more clarity to the answer:*

- In **Edit tab**, check "**allow users to select existing nodes**"
  as shown below

[image]

- In your content creation form, you could find two buttons: **Add New Node** and **Add Existing Node**  as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Inline Entity Form settings are in the **Edit** tab, not the **Field settings** one. Once I realized this, it was easy to find *Allow users to add existing nodes* checkbox. Once it's checked, there are two buttons on field's list: a button for creating a new reference, and one for referring the existing nodes.

Answer (score 3):

The important yet confusing step I observed when wanting to add an existing term, for example, was to make sure you select "Inline entity form - Multiple values" not single values (see https://www.drupal.org/node/2134035). The current patch needs community review.

Comment: In what version? Because I don't remember it to be an issue.

Comment: AFAIK, this is a long-standing issue (that still hasn't been resolved). See https://www.drupal.org/node/2134035

Comment: @Molot which version do you have? I test 1.6 and dev and both have the issue

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer this was long time ago. If you have the same issue, see linked patch file, it looks like a good thing.